# python speech_recognition adding speakers to results

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am using python speech_recognition module to transcribe an audio file into text. However, in the text file i'm using, there are two voices speaking. I would like to know if there is anyway that I can split up the output to two different speakers.

If that is a bit ambiguous I will re-explain. The audio file contains two people, having a conversation. I want the python program to transcribe the audio file to text, including two speakers. For example, the output should look like this:

Speaker 1: Hi there, my name is Josh
Speaker 2: Nice to meet you, my name is Aiden 
etc...

So far, my program is able to properly transcribe an audio file to plain text.

Comment: did you find the solution? because I want to do that too